# How to add network tag when creating compute node in Slurm-GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, slurm

I would like to automatically add network-tag(http-server, https-server) to compute node which is automatically created by slurm-gcp .

After creating a node, the method of manually adding it using the gcloud command is temporarily used.

However, as more nodes are created, the time of manual addition becomes too slow.

I created a custom image and created an instance template using that image. (including http-server and https-server)

However, it does not appear to utilize the instance template at all when created.

I wonder how to solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

I modified the partial code that creates the network tag of the compute node in the slurm/scripts/resume.py file.

```
'tags': {'items': ['compute']},
-------
'tags': {'items': ['compute', 'http-server', 'https-server']},
```

changed below.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#labels_tags):

> If you need to create a tag on a VM, you must create the tag manually.

You can assign network tags to new VMs at creation time, or you can edit the set of assigned tags at any time later. You can edit network tags without stopping a VM.You can also add tags to, and remove tags from, an existing VM.

Check out the documentation on [Configuring network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags).

Comment: I created a network tag in the GCP firewall and attached it to the slurm network, but it is not applied to the node being created.