# Why does the login node connect to external networks but allocated compute node fail in Slurm-GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, wget, slurm, ssh-tunnel

I've noticed that connecting to the internet from the allocated compute node via Slurm-GCP keeps failing. For example, using `wget` from the login node works successfully:

```
[me@gcp-login0 ~]$ wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz
--2023-05-11 19:06:34--  https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz
Resolving cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)... 111.111.1.111, 111.111.11.111, 111.111.111.111, ...
Connecting to cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)|111.111.1.111|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 102167060 (97M) [application/x-xz]
Saving to: ‘linux-4.17.2.tar.xz’

100%[======================================>] 102,167,060  277MB/s   in 0.4s   

2023-05-11 19:06:35 (277 MB/s) - ‘linux-4.17.2.tar.xz’ saved [102167060/102167060]
```

But on a single allocated GPU, `wget` stalls and fails:

```
[me@gcp-compute-0-0 ~]$ wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz

Resolving cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)... 111.111.1.111, 111.111.11.111, 111.111.111.111, ...

Connecting to cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)|151.101.1.176|:443... 

failed: Connection timed out.
```

Accordingly, I was wondering if there's a way to solve this network issue for compute nodes on Slurm-GCP? I tried modifying firewall settings and VPC network details, but it seems to only affect the login node and unable to target the compute node settings on GCP.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791981/how-to-add-network-tag-when-creating-compute-node-in-slurm-gcp) seems like it could be relevant, but I do not see `resume.py` in `/slurm/scripts/`